# Buying a new engine for my 2002 honda civic lx

Tags: engine, civic, vtec

So I found a 2001 2005 HONDA CIVIC 1.7L 4 CYLINDER SOHC VTEC ENGINE JDM D17A and I just want to know if it is compatible with my 2002 Honda civic lx everything is stock except for it had headers when I bought it. I'm just trying to find out if the computer from my stock civic will work with the VTEC I'm looking into or do i need to convert anything.

Comment: No a stock ecu will not do a vtech, but get the ecu with the vtech engine you are buying. If you did not, then go back and get it.

Comment: @juhist when you edited the OP's question you missed a vtech....